# Can I be sure of Last Insert Id of Mysql?

Tags: mysql, .net

I have the latest version of Connector/Net.

I know that there is a property of `MySqlCommand` called `LastInsertedId`.

Can I be sure that it returns last insert id? I mean, when there are two inserts simultaneously, can I be sure that I'll get the right value?

## How I came across this?

I've never used that property. Now I'm designing a new blogging feature in my website.

So , if two end users, through coincidence, create blogs at the same time, can I be sure to get the right value?

Comment: yeah. I'll in my edit

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by `the right value` ? This function will give last generated auto_increment value *for this session*, this is clearly described in doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id  `This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own.`

Comment: @kordirko my right value meant the latest id.Why don't you post it as a answer so that I mark it as answer?

Comment: @AmitJoki, that's better than my answer? It's the same answer.

Comment: No thank you, this is not an answer, it's just an expert from documentation, I'am glad that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want a separate database connection/session for each user/session logged into your web server.

`LAST_INSERT_ID` returns the last autoincrement value for the current connection/session.

Comment: Mate, Its kinda SO. Suppose two users ask different question at same time, what will it return? It isn't possible to have separate connection for different users

Comment: Mate you confused me with `web server` and `session`. Ok, I'll accept your answer